# Scroll de menu no deja subir Jquery Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente formulario

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row" >
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">ADAPTOR CHATBOT</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="container" id="contenedor" style="overflow-y: auto; height:500px;">
            <div class="row message-bubble"><p class="text-muted">Adaptor ChatBot</p><p>Hola! para que te podamos ayudar debes introducir la palabra usuario seguido de tu nombre de usuario y la palabra password seguida de tu password</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
             <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtChat" onkeypress="return runScript(event)" >
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button onclick="charla()" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Enviar</button>
              </span>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

con la sguiente funcion

```
    function ScrollView(){ 
    setInterval(function(){if(window.parar)return;document.getElementById('contenedor').scrollTop=document.getElementById('contenedor').scrollHeight},30); 

     }
```

el tema es que si realiza el scroll hacia abajo automatico , pero no me permite subir el scroll para arriba de nuevo , desde ay gracias

Javascript o Jquery me sirve

Comment: Es posible que el intervalo sea muy corto? Y se esté bajando constantemente impidiendote subirlo?

Comment: mi idea es que baje cada vez que alguien escribe en el chat , y lo llamo en ese momento , al agregar , aunque de igual forma no deja subir  ,

Comment: En la función `ScrollView()` tienes un `setInterval()`. Esto hace que la llamada se ejecute constantemente en un intervalo de 30 (0,03 segundos!). Por lo que entiendo, no necesitas que se llame automáticamente cada X tiempo, sino sólo cuando alguien escriba en el chat.

Comment: Bueno si , puedo sacarle el setInterval y andaria igual?

Comment: Entiendo que sin el setInterval ya no tendrías el problema de no poder subir el scroll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba a quitar el `setInterval`, ya que se está ejecutando cada 0,03 segundos (3000 = 3 segundos).

```
function ScrollView(){ 
    function(){
      if(window.parar)
        return;
      document.getElementById('contenedor').scrollTop=document.getElementById('contenedor').scrollHeight
    }; 
}
```

Llama a la función `ScrollView()` sólamente cuando lo necesites (alguien escriba en el chat, en tu caso), en vez de dejar que se ejecute cada tan poco tiempo.

Comment: lo probare gracias

Comment: Fantástico , soy muy tonto , muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Me pasó lo mismo y lo solucioné agregando un fin de evento de animación en cada caso:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0},1000);

$('html,body').animate(nulla);
});
```